# Could not autowired the interface in other module of monorepo

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface, monorepo

I have created a interface as below :
This is some diiferent , I need to implement this in seperate module in monorepo structure

```
public interface StorageService {

  String generatePreSignedUrlForFetch(String objKey);

  String generatePreSignedUrlForUpload(String objKey);
}
```

and implentation of above StorageService is here

```
@Service
public class S3StorageService implements StorageService {

  private static final long EXPIRY_TIME = (long) 1000 * 60 * 60;

  @Value("${app.storageBucket}")
  private String s3BucketName;

  @Value("${app.tempPath}")
  private String tempPath;

  @Override
  public String generatePreSignedUrlForFetch(String objKey) {
    var preSignedUrlRequest =
        new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3BucketName, objKey)
            .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .withExpiration(getExpiration(EXPIRY_TIME));
    return generatePreSignedUrl(preSignedUrlRequest);
  }

  @Override
  public String generatePreSignedUrlForUpload(String objKey) {
    final GeneratePresignedUrlRequest preSignedUrlRequest =
        getGeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3BucketName, objKey);
    return generatePreSignedUrl(preSignedUrlRequest);
  }

  private Date getExpiration(long expiryTime) {
    final var expiration = new java.util.Date();
    long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
    expTimeMillis += expiryTime;
    expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);
    return expiration;
  }
```

And now I am using storage service in other service class as follows:

```
public class UserService {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;
  private final CandidateRepository candidateRepository;
  private final CompanyRecruiterRepository companyRecruiterRepository;
  private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;
  private final StorageService storageService;
  private static final String PROFILE_IMAGE = "profileImage";

  public User create(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
  }
```

But i am getting error as below, can  anyone resolve this or where i did a mistake

`
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-25 13:46:56,985 [ERROR] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter --

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 4 of constructor in com.recruitnow.tenant.user.service.UserService required a bean of type 'com.recruitnow.api.StorageService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.recruitnow.api.StorageService' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 0 
I tried in monorepo as attached  below project structure[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR9DN.png)`

Comment: I don't see any attempt at autowiring, I also don't see how that other service is configured, or instantiated